How do you pronounce ?
How do you pronounce the word 

 is an old akkadian word for:


fallen fruit
old fruit
dried fruit
something falling from the sky or a tree
something flowing, running, or trickling down


A link to an audio file on the wikipedia commons would be helpful.
Alternatively, IPA notation would help.

Where did you find this word? Those signs look to me like qa-áz-bi which isn't an Akkadian word I recognize.

Why the downvotes?

 qa-áš-bi, normalised as qašbi, is the genitive of ⁠qašbu⁠ and doesn't actually mean all of that. It's attested exactly once in the Akkadian corpus (in Neo-Babylonian, not Old Akkadian, though I don't think that's what you were saying; the attested form is the genitive, which is presumably why yours is) and seems to refer to a specific kind of date. It's probably a loanword from Aramaic קַשְׁבָּא qašbā, which means 'dried date'.
(Your last purported meaning seems to come from Arabic قَسَبَ qasaba 'to flow, to run, to trickle down'—in fact, that's the exact wording of the Wiktionary entry for that verb—but even though the root is homonymous with that of قَسْب qasb 'dried dates' it's not actually the same one; قَسْب is a loan from Aramaic as well.)
The phonetics of Akkadian aren't known with a great deal of certainty, and inconveniently particularly the emphatic stops (like q) and the sibilants are in dispute.
q is conventionally taken to have been an ejective velar stop /k’/ (as in Amharic), but it's possible it was glottalised or pharyngealised or just a uvular stop /q/ (as in Arabic and indeed Aramaic), and that it changed over time. In school pronunciations in languages that don't have any of those it's commonly just a plain voiceless velar stop /k/.
š is typically taken to have been /ʃ/, though that's somewhat hard to square with how it assimilates to dentals and it may have been /s/ instead (or at certain times/places); in school pronunciations it's universally /ʃ/. Aramaic קַשְׁבָּא certainly would have had /ʃ/ as well.
So /'qaʃ.bu/ is probably a plausible guess for how ⁠qašbu would have been pronounced at the time, and I myself would pronounce it /'kaʃ.bu/.

š also varies by dialect, but of course school pronunciations don't care about that.
